# How to use statistics to improve our site?

Tags: data-analysis

Someone has asked me:

> - Which way to measure 'why customer leaves our site?' or 'closes our apps' ?
> - How to complete our statistics and KPI that are More complete & More perfect?
> - How can we relate changes in visit by our customer (in [Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/) statistics) and the new improvement that we apply it?
> - How can we design a survey and how can we send it to the customer so that our image in the customer's mind does not get worse?

Comment: Welcome to SQA, saber.  The title and the questions are different subjects.  Do you want to know the role of statistics, or you asking us to answer those questions?

Comment: OK thanks. please edit .. my English is not good. so i cant find any good tags for my question.

Comment: How have you approached any of these questions so far? What have you tried? For instance, did you try to talk to your users (or people you know) why they leave or would leave your app? Do you need quantitative (which reason is prevalent) or qualitative (what's wrong with the site?) feedback?

Comment: These are good questions, but they are too broad to ask  in aggregate.  Would you please close this question and open four separate questions instead?

Comment: External firms can help you design surveys that can target information on only what you want to know, checking around your region might help.  SurveyMonkey is a popular method to gain information, being internet based, can also provide more accessibility and anonymity to Users who want to respond to the survey.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is really less of an SQA question, and more about "how to I use web site analytics"?

You can search for "website analytics" to learn more.

And this might help:
http://analytics.blogspot.com/

Comment: Some of them are about web site analytics, but there is also a question about survey design.

Comment: yes , also about survey design, those are related together. please help me about that. please

Comment: Again, less of an SQA question, and more about "how does one go about designing effective surveys?" You might wish to search for the terms "designing effective surveys". I did - and found a lot of useful-looking results like: http://help2.surveymonkey.com/articles/en_US/SurveyMonkeyArticleType/Design-Tips-How-to-create-and-administer-effective-surveys.